# How to properly re-map types from .proto files to Typescript and vice versa?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-node

Let's imagine I have 2 Nest.js services: Service A and Service B, which communicate using gRPC. I am trying to pass an object of type **UserSettings** from Service A to Service B via Remote Procedure Call (RPC)

Let's imagine in service A we have types:

```js
enum Language {
  AMERICAN_ENGLISH = "en/us",
  BRITISH_ENGLISH = "en/uk",
  ITALIAN = "it"
}

type UserSettings = {
  theme: "dark" | "white";
  language: Language;
  device: string | number;
}
```

How to correctly map UserSettings with this rich Typescript type to .proto file?

I have reached the point where I understand I **can not use** as many features in protobufs as I can in Typescript.

So, should I use some mapper functions, to map **UserSettings to UserSettingsProto** before calling rpc in Service A, and then in Service B, to map from UserSettingsProto to UserSettings, or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

You should **always** map Protocol Buffer generated types to application types even when this appears to be "perfect".

One tenet of Protobufs that's worth remembering when using a single language, is that the mechanism permits RPCs between code from multiple languages. It's possible to represent any (!?) language-specific type using Protobuf's types (even though sometimes it may seem contorted to do so).

This not only provides a degree-of-freedom from the potential for changes in the stubs and avoids nuances in the stub types but it permits the addition of (see below) e.g. `toString` functions for mapping `enum`s to strings.

You can map `enum`:

```protobuf
enum Language {
  AMERICAN_ENGLISH = 0; // 0 must be used and it is the default value
  BRITISH_ENGLISH = 1;
  ITALIAN = 2;
  ...
}
```

**NOTE** TypeScript's support for string(-mapped) enums would need to be manifest as some `toString` type function in your code.

```protobuf
message UserSettings {
  bool theme = 1;            // Or another enum
  Language language = 2;
  oneof device {             // See NOTE below
    string foo = 1;
    uint32 bar = 2;
}
```

**NOTE** [`oneof`](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/proto3/#oneof) permits union types like your `device` but the implementation differs by langauge. Generally (except Go!?) the name of the `oneof` type (here `device`) doesn't manifest in the stub. Either way, Protobufs requires that each possible type be named i.e. `device` when it's a string (here `foo`) and `device` when it's a number (here `uint32` and `bar`).